# TFS 2017 share nuget packages with other team collection

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore

In my TFS 2017, I have two team projects collection. The first collection generate nuget packages in its collection nuget feed. I would can restore this packages from a project's build that is in the second team project collection. Is it possible and how ?

When I restore I have a 401 error and I don't see how to add permissions to restore from other collection projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Adding the feed in Nuget.config file like the sample below in the second project and specify the Nuget.config path in your build definition

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="TFSFeed" value="http://tfssetver:8080/tfs/teamprojectCollection/_packaging/TFSFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
</packageSources>
```

> Make sure you are running the build agent under the account that can
>   access the feed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, though the error was not 401, but "error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://.../nuget/v3/index.json". (a package from another collection in TFS).
I solved it by changing Pipeline in TFS. In section Restore i had task version 1 (DotNetCoreCLI@1). I changed it to version 2 (DotNetCoreCLI@2). Everything has been successfully restored.